# Using function to Apply the Hadamard product in 2 matrices 3x3 in C

Tags: c, function, matrix-multiplication

I tried to separate this code using two int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(){
    int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3],i,d,e;
    puts("multiplica 2 matrices de 3x3");
    puts("Matriz A");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int d=0; d<3; d++){
            printf("introdusca el dato %d,%d\t",i+1,d+1);
            scanf ("%d",&a[i][d]);
            }
        }
    puts("Matriz B");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int d=0; d<3; d++){
            printf("introdusca el dato %d,%d\t",i+1,d+1);
            scanf ("%d",&b[i][d]);
            }
        }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int d=0; d<3; d++){
        c[i][d]=a[i][d]*b[i][d];
            }
        }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("| ");
        for (int d=0; d<3; d++){
            printf("%4.2d",c[i][d]);
            }
        printf("|");
        printf("\n");
        }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

With `void` it worked very well but I had troubles when I tried using `int` giving me random numbers instead of the real multiplication expected by the last code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int mult(int x[3][3], int y[3][3]){
int c[3][3];
    for (int k=0; k<3; k++){
        for (int l=0; l<3; l++){
        c[k][l]=x[k][l]*y[k][l];
            }
        }
    return c[3][3];
}
int main (){
    int a[3][3],b[3][3],i,j;
    puts("multiplica 2 matrices de 3x3");
    puts("Matriz A");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            printf("introdusca el dato %d,%d\t",i+1,j+1);
            scanf ("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    puts("Matriz B");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            printf("introdusca el dato %d,%d\t",i+1,j+1);
            scanf ("%d",&b[i][j]);
            }
        }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("|");
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%4.2d",mult(a,b));
            }
        printf(" |");
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess the way I put the `printf("%4.2d",mult(a,b));` inside the for loop doesn't assign the data on `int mult` or doesn't return "c" correctly.

Comment: `return c[3][3];` is out of the bounds of your 3x3 matrix.

Comment: If you fix the trivial problems, it will still be a Hadamard product, not a normal matrix product. Is that intentional?

Comment: @harold Yes, it's actually a Hadamard product, I'm just lost solving it with `int`.

Answer (score -1):

Ok if it is Hadamard calculations were OK. You will need to malloc your matrix before sending back the pointer.

```
int **mult(int x[3][3], int y[3][3])
{
   if (!(c = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3)))
    return (0);

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                c[k][l] = x[k][l] * y[k][l];

    return c;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to return an array.

Comment: It's actually a Hadamard product, sorry to not point it out.
Using `return c;` give me these errors: _10  12 [Error] invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]_ and _4   5 [Warning] address of local variable 'c' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]_ that's why I tried with `c[3][3]`